# NSData to NSArray; Array empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdata

When I try to convert NSData to NSArray the array is empty. I know the data is not nil because I NSLogged it. Here is the code:

```
    NSData *arrayData = [NSData dataWithData:folderOpened.arrayOfItems];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:arrayData]];
    NSLog(@"%d",arrayData.length);
    NSLog(@"array count:%d",array.count);
```

My NSLog:

```
 285
 array count:0
```

My objects NSCoding protocols:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

}
 -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{ 
     return nil;
}
```

Comment: Are your objects NSCoding compliant?

Comment: The array is empty, or nonexistent?  I suspect the latter, because the data was no good.

Comment: @mmackh You mean the objects in the array?

Comment: Yes, are you storing custom objects?

Comment: @HotLicks The array is empty...

Comment: @mmackh Yes I did implement the NSCoding protocols

Comment: Can we see a sample of your object?

Comment: instead of returning nil, try return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

Comment: @mmackh I get error `No visible @interface for NSObject declares initWithCoder`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38275/discussion-between-mmackh-and-abdullah-shafique)

Comment: If the array is empty it will NSLog as `()`.  NSLogging the array count will display zero even if the array does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your custom objects NSCoding compliant to make them work with NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver. 
Here's a great starting point: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/